# Google App Engine - schedulerError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

Below is the error that my application threw and then started a series of `StackOverflowError`, question would be, if TaskQueue timeouts a lot would it cause the StackOverflowError?

```
[INFO] SEVERE: Job somepath-fast.task-345bddcf-a8f1-471f-8974-e285746e9c78 threw an unhandled Exception: 
[INFO] com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 5: http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/somepath timed out.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:407)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(LocalTaskQueue.java:701)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:90)
[INFO]  at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
[INFO]  at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apr 27, 2018 10:06:25 AM org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger schedulerError
[INFO] SEVERE: Job (somepath-fast.task-345bddcf-a8f1-471f-8974-e285746e9c78 threw an exception.
[INFO] org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 5: http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/somepath timed out.]
[INFO]  at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:214)
[INFO]  at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
[INFO] * Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
[INFO] com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 5: http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/somepath timed out.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:407)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(LocalTaskQueue.java:701)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:90)
[INFO]  at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
[INFO]  at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

Comment: i'm not sure about your question, but i know how to fix it. I've faced this problem a couple times. Task Queue's apparently need to be constructed differently in development environment than on production environment.

Comment: Can you share the fix? @JonathanLaliberte

Comment: are you not able to run your task in development right?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte The app can run Tasks on devserver but somehow starts throwing SO error after 30 minutes or more, time is really variable here. So answer is yes it works but for a limited time.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code, how are you using Task Queues? Here [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/example ] there is an example that shows how to add tasks to a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah after the comment exchange the problem does sound familiar. If it is the same problem, i was able to fix this by doing the following:

Normal taskqueue goes something like this (doesn't work in dev):

```
Queue myQueue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
SendDailyQuote myTask = new SendDailyQuote();
myQueue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(myTask));
```

In development environment:

```
//Queue myQueue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
SendDailyQuote myTask = new SendDailyQuote();
//myQueue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(myTask));
myTask.run();
```